# Images getting from url and how to decrease the image size in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

My problem is: I am getting image from server. When I get images from server image size 138x91 but I had given my images size is in my custom cell size 85x56. Its loading good. But when I click row its increase the server image size. How to decrease the image size when i get image in my tableview and how to don't change image size when i click row.how to solve my problem.i want Images getting from url and how to decrease the image size in iOS.goto bellow link.
1).before click.
http://radiokhushi.com/siri-admin/uploads/Beforclick.png
2).ofter click
http://radiokhushi.com/siri-admin/uploads/ofterclick.png

this is image getting data code in cell for row at index path.and loading before i am showing one placeholderimage.

```
 newsobject.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^{
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb_file"]]];

                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = image;

            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you please show whole code for `cellforrowatindexpath` ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this method :

```
 UIImage *croppedimg = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] convertToSize:CGSizeMake(95, 95)]; // here resize your image whatever you want.

 - (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size
 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return destImage;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image. get the appropriate size of the image.

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image withWidth:(int) width withHeight:(int) height {

    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    CGContextRef bitmap;

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp | image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

    } else {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, height, width, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

    }

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        NSLog(@"image orientation left");
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

    } else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        NSLog(@"image orientation right");
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

    } else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        NSLog(@"image orientation up");

    } else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        NSLog(@"image orientation down");
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-180.));

    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: when i implement this method i got two errors 1).  "_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS", referenced from:
2).clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to determine what exactly the issue without seeing code in the tableview delegates.

However, I'm thinking if you set a proper `contentMode` of the imageView will solve your problem.

After setting your image, set the contentMode accordingly, perhaps something like this:

```
newsobject.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
newsobject.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIImageView+WebCache.h & .m` Classes for download your images. You can search for these classes on github or google. It provides you different different method to download images asynchronously and also provides functions to resize the images according to our app requirement. Use this below method:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options: (SDWebImageOptions)options  andResize:(CGSize)size withContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)mode;
```

I hope this can help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I am download and import this one UIImageView+WebCache.h and implement this method bun didn't solve my problem and this method is didn't call when i run program

Comment: @venky If the method is not getting call, then first you should debug for the program that why the line is not getting execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
[newsobject.allnewsimg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_file"]]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songs85-56.png"]];
```

Comment: when use this one i am easily solve image sizes (small to large)problem.and we have to download 'SDWebImage'framework and import  #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h" this one.